# Understanding the fragment and activity lifecycle and backwards navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-navigation

I'm trying to understand some odd behavior. I have an ActivityA that calls a method in onCreate() to add FragmentA to R.id.fragment_container. Inside FragmentA I have a button that attaches FragmentB by using ActivityA's fragment manager (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()) and replacing the R.id.fragment_container and I also add it to the backstack. I also have another button that starts a new ActivityB.
When I navigate back from ActivityB I get: ActivityA onResume(), FragmentA onResume(). But when I navigate back from FragmentB I get: FragmentB onCreateView(), FragmentB onActivityCreated() then the 2 onResume().

So my questions is...why is the view state saved when a new activity is launched and not when the fragment is replaced and reattached. It looks much better to just restore that state rather than recreate the views and fetch that data again. This seems like opposite behavior from what I would expect so I'm clearly missing some fragment state saving/restoration step or something. It seems like the activity is just pausing FragmentA (and ActivityA) when ActivityB is launched and restoring it on back pressed but when FragmentB is attached FragmentA gets completely destroyed. I'm sure there's a way to prevent this I just can't seem to figure it out. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just below your question are four tags android,android-fragments,android-lifecycle& android-navigation .Put your cursor over it for a while a black box will pop up . click on info tab and you will get best links to study that topics along with links to books .

Hope this will help you